# Multiple versions of Python and pip on my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: uninstall, python3

I have multiple versions of Python (2.7 - Default, 3.5, 3.7.0a1 ) installed on my server. And along with that pip also got installed. I want to remove all except 2.7. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; however Ubuntu very heavily relies on python, and for a long time that's been python3, so removal of python3 will cause many Ubuntu tools to no longer work and you'll end up needing to maintain your system yourself using only basic (no end-user) tools (ie. you may not longer be able to access `apt` `apt-get` and common tools, automated upgrade tools also will no longer function etc)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm *The python3 mentioned is not used by any supported release of Ubuntu, closest is 16.04 ESM*